# How to create report using ReportViewer Control for Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 tables in Microsoft Access 2007.

The table name  "BillDetail" and "BillMaster"

Fields contained in BillMaster is : BillNO,  BillType,  Dt,  PartyName

Fields contained in BillDetail table is : BillNo(Ref) Serial No.  Desc  HSNCode  Qty  Rate.

I need to fetch data from both tables. The Master Record should be displayed in header and all the related items should be displayed in tabular form. And I finally want to print these information as a bill.

My basic need is not to use the crystal reports. I searched a lot over internet and found a solution that to use the ReportViewer Control. But unfortunately I don't know how to build report using this control. Please help me to generate the report or post some links of tutorial.

Please help. I am totally new to Windows Application Development.

Answer (score 2):

The report viewer control is capable of rendering reports that are defined in `rdl` or `rdlc` files.

`rdl` stands for "Report definition language" and the "C" stands for "Client Reports" that is vs. "Server Reports"

so if you don't have a reporting server installed you would probably be best using `rdlc` and attaching your Access 2007 DB as the datasource for your report.

here are several tutorials for creating `rdlc` reports files and using report viewer control:

[CodeProject - How to connect a report i.e. rdlc file with the project form.](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/398128/How-to-connect-a-report-i-e-rdlc-file-with-the-pro)

[Beginner's guide for creating standalone .rdlc reports with ssrs](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/robo60/StandaloneRDLCReports11142007183516PM/StandaloneRDLCReports.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find an example,How to Generate RDLC Reports in C# with Code Example...

http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-create-rdlc-report-in-c-windows.html#.UgCO6pKfjwg

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;


using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

namespace RDLC
{
    public partial class RD : Form
    {
        public RD()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RD_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = GetData("select * from tbl_Admission_Form");
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "RDLC.Report1.rdlc";
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
            //this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
        private DataTable GetData(string query)
        {
            string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a GetData function like that unless you have a way to pass parameters.